# Backbone.JS Custom Event from Child View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two views, for simplicity sake a parent/child.  The child is using trigger to throw an event.  I am not seeing it in the handler of the parent.  Is the below valid?

```
var parent = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: { "childevent": "run" },
    run: function(e) {
       console.log(e);
    }, 
    render: function() { /* render the child here */ }
});

var child = Backbone.View.extend({
    someAction: function() { this.trigger('childevent'); }
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Figured it out!  `$(this.el).trigger('childevent');` works.

Comment: you can also try this.$el for the cached jQuery property

Comment: and what if i'm following the policy that a view can access only the element its responsible for and its children? how do i event to the parent?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be `events: { "childevent": "run" }` instead? There is no way to access the actual anonymous function in this place in the code.

Comment: I actually had that, however it still doesn't work, I just typed it up wrong here.  Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone store a jQuery reference to the view's node in `this.$el` property so you can spare some performance using it rather than re-compute the reference by `$(this.el)`.

```
// use "this.$el.trigger()" to refer to jQuery's object
this.$el.trigger('childevent');
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously late, but for anyone else who comes across this:

the events property on a view is for auto-binding Html DOM events from components within the views el or $el elements, and the syntax involves both a UI event and a selector as the key in pair:

events: { "click #someButton", "clickHandler" }

To listen to events from other Models or Views, you use this.listenTo( target, ..... )